# Execute http request inside NgZone with Angular2

Tags: angular, zone, zonejs

I'm wondering how I can execute an http request where I update the profile view within the Angular2 Zone. In my top level profile component I'm currently doing a single simple http request using `authHttp`:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private auth: Auth,
        private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // update profile information
        let headers: any = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

        this.authHttp
            .get('https://' + myConfig.domain + '/api/v2/users/' + this.auth.userProfile.user_id, {headers: headers})
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.auth.userProfile = response;
                    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                error => console.log(error.json().message)
            );

    }
}
```

The issue is that since this request is asynchronous, the profile page loads **before** this request is fulfilled and the profile is updated. What happens is on the first time I click refresh nothing happens, because the old data is loaded into profile and the new data AFTER. Then second time I hit refresh everything works, because it's only then using the new data loaded from the last request.

Is this issue solvable using `NgZone`? Can I somehow include this request into the zone so when it finishes it reevaluates the component tree?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by this. What isn't updating? Your View? Are you binding to the auth.userProfile in your View? And it's not updating when the request through authHttp comes back?

Comment: @Steveadoo I'm passing some pieces of data from `auth.userProfile` as input into another component in the template of the profile component, so it's passing the old data in as input before the `auth.userProfile` can be updated by the http request

Comment: How do you know it's a zone issue? Looking at AuthHttp, it doesn't look like it'd run outside of angular's zone. If you pass the auth.userProfile in as @Input() properties into your other component, it should automatically update then when you change it. Do you happen to be reading the @Input properties inside of the ngOnInit in this other component?

Comment: @Steveadoo I am indeed reading and using the `@input` properties in the other components NgOnInit, would that be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Yessir, try to make them setters, and then call some sort of update method on it. I will post an answer that's more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I don't think it has anything to do with Zones. You need to update your secondary component when your @Input properties change.

```
export class SecondaryComponent {

    private _myProperty: any;
    @Input()
    set myProperty(val: any) {
        this._myProperty = val;
        this.update();
    }

    update() { //instead of ngOnInit just use this
        //do stuff with _myProperty now
    }

}
```

However, why can't you just bind to the auth.userProfile field inside that secondary component? Unless you transform the data somehow inside your secondary components ngOnInit method, that would probably be easier.